# How to represent “Recurring Events” in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing an application that will need to allow the site admin to schedule "events" and allow visitors to reserve or book a place at the events.

To minimise admin work I need to allow the admin to create an event and mark it as recurring on a schedule.  In most cases this will be "weekly" but "every 2 weeks", "monthly" etc may also be needed at some point.

I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure out (with many Google & SO searches already) how to model this in MySQL.

I understand that I need to keep the "event entry" items separate and then only add "event instances" to the schedule when needed (i.e. the first person books a place, the date arrives,  the instance is edited independently of the series, etc.)

I just can't seem to get my head around how this should be actually recorded in the database without it feeling nasty.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd been thinking about something similar wrt a hobby project.

My conclusion was that it would be easier to maintain a table of individual scheduled events (instances) and a seperate table of recurring events (i.e. not populating the instance table with records for the recurring events) then to merge the recurring events in the response to a query.

This also entails that you would implement a querying API which requires a start and end time for schedule requests (or understands about recurring events and instances).

And to simplify handling the case where e.g. a recurring event is scheduled for each week, then to put the *exception* in the instance table.

Consider - if you create instances for recurring events - someone schedules a weekly event with no end date. How many records do you put into the instances table? How do you detect when they've run out? How do you deal with the instances when the owner cancels the schedule?

Have a look at the ical / vcalendar docs for ideas.

You might also want to have a look at how this is handled by applications such as phpcalendar.

Comment: I was originally thinking 3 tables but after looking at my diagram it didn't feel right.  I'm going to mark this as the answer as it makes more sense than what my frazzled brain was coming up with.  Thanks